# How to Clear/Remove JavaScript Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Given the following HTML fragment:

```
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="alert('On Submit Run!'); return true;">
```

I need to remove/clear the handler for the onsubmit event and register my own using jQuery or any other flavor of JavaScript usage.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

To do this without any libraries:

```
document.getElementById("aspnetForm").onsubmit = null;
```

Comment: I may have spoke to soon - this does not appear to work on IE 6 or 7.  It reports an error: "Not implemented".

Comment: Hmm... does it work if you set it to null instead of undefined?  Although undefined *should* be the correct setting, null may work.

Comment: out of curiosity, will setting object.eventhandler=null return 'undefined' as typeof object.eventhandler?

Comment: `document.getElementById("aspnetForm").removeAttribute('onsubmit')`

Comment: What about setting it to `''`? I’ve seen that numerous times in place of `null`. Is either better?

Comment: Only removeAttribute worked in Chrome (Tampermonkey). I didn't try `undefined`, but I did try `delete`.

Answer (score 26):

With jQuery

```
$('#aspnetForm').unbind('submit');
```

And then proceed to add your own.

Comment: Then I'm not sure - it's the "jQuery way" to remove event listeners.

Comment: You can only unbind event listeners that were added with jQuery's `bind()` method.

Comment: instead you can use $.die('submit')

Answer (score 11):

Try this, this is working for me:

```
$('#aspnetForm').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit(function() {   
    alert("My new submit function justexecuted!"); 
});
```

See [this](http://joshuaclayton.github.com/code/2009/06/08/handling-jquery-and-onsubmit.html) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

This is an ancient question now, but given that the major browsers have all abandoned `EventTarget.getEventListeners()`, here's a way to remove **ALL** event handlers on the element and its children and retain only the HTML structure. We simply clone the element and replace it:

```
let e = document.querySelector('selector');
let clone = e.cloneNode(true);
e.replaceWith(clone);
```

This is just as much of a hack as preempting the `addEventListener()` prototype with a method that keeps track of every handler function, but at least this can be used after the DOM is already wired up with another script's events.

This also works about the same as above using jQuery's [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead of `cloneNode()`:

```
let original = $('#my-div');
let clone = original.clone();
original.replaceWith(clone);
```

This pattern will effectively leave no event handlers on the element or its child nodes unless they were defined with an ["on" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) like `onclick="foo()"`.

Answer (score 3):

For jQuery, [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/#off) removes all event handlers added by jQuery from it.

```
$('#aspnetForm').off();
```

> Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.

Comment: This only removes event handlers that were added using jQuery. 
Any event handlers added using vanilla JS or by any other method won't be removed.

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery, if you are binding event handlers with .live, you can use .die to unbind all instances that were bound with .live.

Comment: [`.die()` is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803936/how-to-clear-remove-javascript-event-handler#comment27087086_803946)