# Unbinding inline onClick not working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so, I'm wondering how to unbind an inline onclick event in jQuery.  You'd think `.unbind()` would work, however it doesn't.

To test this for yourself, play around with the following HTML and JavaScript:

```
function UnbindTest() {
    $("#unbindTest").unbind('click');
}

function BindTest() {
    $("#unbindTest").bind('click', function() { alert("bound!"); });
}


<button type="button" onclick="javascript:UnbindTest();">Unbind Test</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:BindTest();">Bind Test</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('unbind me!');" id="unbindTest">Unbind Button</button>
```

As you can see, unbinding does not unbind the inline `onclick` event... however it does unbind the click event added with `bind()`.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to unbind inline onclick events short of doing the following:

```
$("#unbindTest").get(0).onclick = "";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

jQuery's unbind won't work on `onclick` attributes - it only works for functions that were added via `bind` and thus are available in `$(...).data('events')`. You have to use `removeAttr` to remove `onclick`.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804021/why-this-unbind-doesnt-work) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

[`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) unbinds event handlers registered with `bind`, not ones assigned via the `onclick` or other DOM0 attributes. From the docs:

> Any handler that has been attached with `.bind()` can be removed with `.unbind()`.

**Edit**: You unbind DOM0 handlers by clearing the relevant attribute on the element. I had to go look up the jQuery way of doing that: [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).