# jQuery - onclick: Why does it execute click right on adding handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, onclick

Question:

I'm having a little trouble with jQuery:
Consider this HTML, where I want to left-click on "https", change it's value and then click ok. On OK, it should remove the textbox, and re-attach the onclick handler.
This is does, but onclick is already issued by the current click...

Why ? And how to do this correctly ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Tabelle editieren</title>
    <!--
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    -->
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        html {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
        body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
        input{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

        tr:nth-child(2n+1) {background-color: #F0F0F0;}
        tr:nth-child(2n)   {background-color: #FEFEFE;}

        td
        {
            margin: 0px; padding: 0.5cm; padding: 0px; text-align: left; 
        }


    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function hello(me) {
            //alert("hello");
            var str = $(me).text();
            //alert(str);
            $(me).html("<input id=\"my1\" type=\"text\" style=\"width: 198px; height: 100%;\" value=\"" + str + "\" /><input id=\"my1confirm\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"bye(this);\"style=\"width: 35px;\" value=\"" + "OK" + "\" />");
            $(me).attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');

            return false;
        }


        function bye(me) {
            var objTR = $(me).parent();

            //var tb = $(me).closest('table');
            var tb = objTR.find('input');
            var str = tb.val();
            tb.remove();

            objTR.text(str);
            alert("TODO: sending change event with { id : \"" + objTR.attr('id') + "\", str : \"" + str + "\" } to server");


            /*
            objTR.click(function () {
                alert("hi");
                return false;
            });
            */


            objTR.attr('onclick', '').bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("it shouldn't  execute this in this click, but it does... ");
                //hello(this);
                //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });

            return false;
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable();

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0.5cm;">
    <h1>Application configuration</h1>
    <!--

    -->
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: Black; color:White; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
          <th style="width: 235px; text-align: left;">key</th>
          <th style="width: 235px; text-align: left;">value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr style="background-color: Black; color:White; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
          <th style="text-align: left;">key</th>
          <th style="text-align: left;">value</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Environment</td>
          <td id="server">testing</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Protocol</td>
          <td id="Protocol" onclick="hello(this);">https</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>UserHashMode</td>
          <td id="UserHashMode">true</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Logo</td>
          <td id="Logo">LogoFileCustomerN.png</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you already tried the methods .on() or .delegated()? I cannot provide any tries, because I'm sitting not on my computer.

Comment: Given you're using jQuery 1.7.1, try using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [`.removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) rather than `.attr()`. Removing or resetting an attribute doesn't necessarily mean the related property value will be changed.

Comment: @reporter: On works so far, but now I can't get it off anymore, lol ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that inline event handlers cannot be unbound by jQuery: [Unbinding inline onClick not working in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768109/unbinding-inline-onclick-not-working-in-jquery)

So I'm not sure if it'll work, but instead of using:

```
.attr("onclick", "")
```

try:

```
.removeAttr("onclick")
```

Let us know if that changes anything.

**UPDATE:**

I made a jsFiddle to show you how it could function "easier": http://jsfiddle.net/S2ARR/3/

A lot of it depends on certain things, such as using my structure - putting a span inside of the column instead of using the column for everything. I didn't use the id of elements for jQuery selecting because I wasn't sure why you weren't - if you set the id of elements and you need to access them, you might as well use the id selector in jQuery. So you wouldn't need to use .parent() or .find() in my example if you just used the id. Hopefully this is what you were looking for. I think the important thing was the .stopPropagation() call, otherwise it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Just updated and gave a small example of what you're looking for, modifying your code a little. It seems to work for me!

Comment: Yep, .stopPropagation() is the real magic. PS: It seems to work fine with td instead of span. Yours is invalid HTML.

Comment: It's up to you whether you want to bind to the whole <td> or a <span>. How is my HTML invalid?

Answer (score 1):

i changed your event to delegate, removed onclick from the table and called it using jquery. However i'm not sure if what i get is your desire behavior.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s6vn/11/)

**Update**

Hi, i updated with the desired behavior.

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/3s6vn/45/)

Comment: @Quandary ups, sorry i made it work anyway! hope to be at least a little bit of help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the event via the onclick attribute, you can bind it to the table cell with jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $("#Protocol").click(function(){ 
       // your content
    });
});
```

Then, you can guarantee that you can unbind the event with unbind later on.

Comment: i already tried that, it doesn't make a difference... unbind works btw, the problem is when I try to re-bind.

Comment: Your basic problem is that it's not unbinding, yes?  I had a hard time reading your description.

Comment: No, it's unbinding properly. Rebinding is the problem. As soon as I rebind, I get the click event executed without having clicked...

Comment: OH!, I see.  Let me look at this and get back to you.