# How to edit 'onchange' attribute in a 'select' tag? (using jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, events, select

I'm trying to edit the 'onchange' event of an existent 'select' element.

For example purposes I have the following code:

```
<select id="sel_id" onchange="javascript:foo();" >
```

and whenever I try to change its 'onchange' attribute I was using the following:

```
$("#sel_id").attr("onchange", "foo_2()");
```

FYI, this code which should be fine doesn't work, the 'onchange' attribute remains unchanged. So how should you edit it?

**AMMENDMENT:**

You can remove the attribute and then bind a different function like:

```
$("#sel_id").removeAttr("onchange").bind("change", function(){ foo_2(); });
```

but the issue remains, is it possible to change the 'onchange' attribute without removing it in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not an exact answer to the question, but I'd probably remove the event using this:

```
document.getElementById('sel_id').onchange = undefined;
```

(as seen at [How to Clear/Remove JavaScript Event Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803936/clear-remove-javascript-event-handler) )

and then go with this:

```
$('#sel_id').change(function() { foo_2(); });
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer, I sure need to remove the event and bind my own using jquery.

Comment: `$('sel_id').attr('onchange',undefined).change(function() { foo_2(); });` is the jQuery way to do it.  This way you can just do both operations with one jQuery object.

Comment: Also OP could probably just do `.change(foo_2)` instead of wrapping in an anonymous function.

Comment: @Muhd ur code was not working but when I changed the undefined to null it started working.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me if I use the native `setAttribute()`.

Also, remember that you need quotes around the selector.

```
$("#sel_id")[0].setAttribute("onchange", "foo_2()");
```

Also remember to define `foo_2` in the global namespace, and not inside jQuery's `.ready()` function.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the quotes in the example but were used in real code. (edited the question)    


`setAttribute()` should be the solution for the question, but it actually has the same problem I presented.    
If a 'onchange' attribute is declared in the element it isn't replaced and the old event code is triggered.    


Moreover I would rather use an inner scope function in the onchange event. Thus, I may actually use the code I refer in the ammendment.

Comment: @vitorhsb - From your addition to your question, the issue remains of the `foo()` being called. Is this in IE? You could try setting its `onchange` property to null: `$("#sel_id")[0].onchange = null;`. Not sure if that will help, but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: This is Great! There appears to be a bug in IE8 associated with binding a change event to a select. I've tried almost everything (addEventListener, and jQuery .change and .bind. None worked. But, this did. Thanks!

Comment: @Cary: Glad this worked, but that's very strange that jQuery's event handling didn't work for you. They do a very good job of fixing those browser issues. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery change function.

```
$('#sel_id').change(function() {
  //your code
});
```

Comment: This way it still triggers the onchange event declared in the select tag.

Comment: Then use $('#sel_id').unbind('change') first

Comment: `$('#sel_id').unbind('change')` actually doesn't remove the previous event declared in the html tag, it only removes the bind events declared dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using just javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" langauge="JavaScript">
function foo (){
    alert("foo");
}
function fi() {
    alert('fi');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id = "select_list" onchange="foo();">
<option value = "1">1</option>
<option value = "2">2</option>
</select>
<input type = "button" value = "change" onclick = "document.getElementById('select_list').onchange = fi;">
</body>
</html>
```