# Foolproof Unique title for Urls

Tags: php, uri, character

Within my application UI want to avoid id numbers within the urls if possible so the best way to do this would be to create a a unique version of the title that's valid for url schemas.

SO do a something the same but as the you allow duplicate questions they have the id within the URI!

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637971/how-to-edit-onchange-attribute-in-a-select-tag-using-jquery
```

Wordpress have implemented such features as well

my question is:

**What's the best way to accomplish this, sticking to the URI RFC as well as keeping search engines happy**.

Comment: I believe the concept you're looking for is known as URL Rewriting. I'm not familiar with php specifically enough to help much more than that. Hopefully it'll give you a good starting point though. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Drupal Path/Pathauto modules do this, so I'd check that implementation. For a quick hit, if there are titles that reduce to duplicates:

```
CaseySoftware is awesome
CaseySoftware is awesome!
```

They would become:

```
caseysoftware-is-awesome
caseysoftware-is-awesome-0
```

You will definitely need to scrub out punctuation, but you may want to do the same to common articles like "a, the, is".

Comment: +1 I'd also add you can see which characters are valid by looking at RFC 3986. Follow the definition of `segment`.

Answer (score 1):

### To keep search engine happy

You should use this in your head :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yoursite.com/page/uniqueTitle/"/>
```

This will tell search engine that all page that have that specific canonical name are the same.

For example, this page has the following line :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637990/foolproof-unique-title-for-urls">
```

If you change the title, that value will stay the same. This is how search engine really know it's all the same page.

### How to generate

As for how those URL are generated, you should stick to the lower case alphanumeric characters ([a-z0-9]) and replace space with "-".

Comment: thats for the tip, but my question is more related the actual unique url itself, what chars are valid, what's the best method to keep urls unique if theres a dupe etc.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about having possibly duplicate URL, as long as you have the rel canonical link it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

["Friendly URLs — Possibly all of what makes a good URL structure"](http://semicolons.org/post/256699383/friendly-urls) is a nice article about that topic, and it includes a short example implementation in Python.

To make the URLs really unique without having to use a numeric ID everywhere, I'd try to generate my new URL, see if it already exists (shouldn't occur very often), and only if it does, append a short sequence number at the end.