# How to add onChange attribute for select box from Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have select box with out `onChange` attribute. Now after loading the total page, based on some conditions I have to add `onChange` for the select box from Javascript. I am trying with the following code, but its not working:

```
$("#depositForm").attr(("onChange", "selectedMainDepositType('this');" ));
```

Its is not adding the `onChange` event.

```
<select id="depositForm_depositSubType" class="depositSubType" style="width:160px;" name="depositSubType">
```

has to be changed as

```
<select id="depositForm_depositSubType"  onchange="selectedMainDepositType(this);"  class="depositSubType" style="width:160px;" name="depositSubType">
```

Please suggest how to add the `onChange` attribute.

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use any of the `[on*]` attributes, so don't bother.

Comment: don't think about event as you do with attributes ... in-line events are parsed at document loading and it is not meant to be edited like a classic attribute afterward

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try...

```
$("#depositForm").on("change", function(event) { 
     selectedMainDepositType(this);
} );
```

[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If you need to remove the handler, use `$("#depositForm").off("change");`. Is the attr `onChange` attached when the page is generated?

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#depositForm").change(function(e){
    selectedMainDepositType($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById('depositForm').onchange = undefined;

 $("#depositForm").change(..);
```

Give it a shot.. I hope it works out for you..
Original post [How to edit 'onchange' attribute in a 'select' tag? (using jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637971/how-to-edit-onchange-attribute-in-a-select-tag-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for another answer.
I used this method because I had to first search for the dynamically created select list.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (i=0; i<dropdown.length; i++) {
    if (dropdown[i].title == "Component") {
        dropdown[i].onchange = changeApproverCC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
document.getElementById("depositForm").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
 selectedMainDepositType('this');
});
```

Hope can help you :)