# How to remove event from multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the event for my `input` elements.

I have the following

```
//add mouse up event on all element under mainDiv
addEvent('mainDiv', 'onmouseup', mouseUpFun);

//search all the input elements and remove the mouse up event 
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i; i < inputs.length; i++){
      var input = inputs[i];
       input.removeEventListener('onmouseup');
    }
```

The codes above don't work and still have `onmouseup` event attached to it.

Can anyone help me about this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bit difficult to debug without seeing what `addEvent`does.

Comment: check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803936/how-to-clear-remove-javascript-event-handler

Comment: If you have any other methods than `addEventListener()` attaching events in `addEvent()` function, you probably should create a corresponding `removeEvent()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one reason might be that your loop never runs. You need to initialize `i` in your loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
   var input = inputs[i];
   input.removeEventListener('onmouseup');
}
```

Otherwise this loop will never run due to `i` having the initial value of `undefined`.

Your call to `removeEventListener` also won't work as expected. You will also need to provide a reference to the listener/handler that you used.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) for the proper usage of `removeEventListener`.

If everything is using `mouseUpFun`, you can provide that to `removeEventListener`:

```
input.removeEventListener('onmouseup', mouseUpFun);
```

Comment: The best way to write that would be for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++)

Comment: To avoid the performance drag of recalculating length for each loop iteration

Comment: @CaseyFlynn Is it that much of an impact? Does it have to recalculate it every time? I imagine it just has a property that is updated whenever the array is modified. I'm wary of such performance micro-optimizations.

Comment: @CaseyFlynn Just ran a test-case on jsPerf and it seems like using `array.length` [is marginally faster](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-iteration-performance).

Comment: I'm not sure how console.log affects the test but try this: http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4

Comment: @CaseyFlynn Interesting. Either way, the difference is marginal such that it really doesn't matter. As I said before, it's best to be wary of micro-optimizations.

Comment: I don't know if I would call an 11% improvement a micro-optimization

Comment: @CaseyFlynn Consider the following example: going from .001s to 0.0015s is a 50% difference, but the actual difference in time is only .0005s, which means that even after 50,000 iterations the difference is only 5s. Percentages by themselves don't tell the whole story. Code first, analyze for hotspots later, and *then* optimize. The term "micro optimizations" refers to minor optimizations that bring marginal benefit; "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Also, take a look at [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: I just use coffeescript. Takes care of this and many other things like it.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener

When you use `removeEventListener`, you need a reference to the listener function you want to remove.

Then, you could:

- With your `addEvent` function you could save references of the listeners you add

or

- You could clone the element and replace it with the clone. This way you will delete ALL event listeners (including its childs' event listeners).