# How to unbind keyup event?

Tags: javascript

I have html code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="search1" class="search" id="search_term" onkeyup="check_search(e,this.value,'searchkey');">
```

And i want to unbind this key event on the document ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementById('search_term').onkeyup = null;`

Inline event handler attributes are assigned to the `oneventname` property of the element, so just set it to null to detach the event listener.

Answer (score 4):

**If you want a JavaScript only solution**

You can just set the event listener to null.

```
document.getElementById("search_term").onkeyup = null;
```

Refer to this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/803984/3747743

**If you use jQuery**

You have to use the `unbind` method.

An example:

```
var handler = function() {
  alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

For more informations: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on the question, nor any mention of jQuery in the question body.

Comment: Basically stealing my answer now :p I'm kidding ^_^ But it still baffles me why people would use jQuery for something that can be done with *less* code in Vanilla JS...

Comment: I don't steal your answer, I just provide two solutions. I think this page can be visited by a lot of people because it's a common question, so I try to be as complete as possible.

Comment: That's why I said I'm kidding. It's just that you ended up adding, character-for-character bar the use of double-quotes, the exact same code as mine ;)

Comment: It's working for onkeyup. but same is not working for 
`<input type="submit" name="" value="" class="searchbtn" onclick="search_button();">`
How to unbind this onclick?
I had tried it with unbind but It's not working.