# Unable to disable click event from element with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to detach `click` event from several `p` elements via plain JavaScript. I'm able to access these `p` elements, but for some reason I'm not able to remove the `click` listener. It works fine with `jQuery`, but not with pure `JS`. `getP_element` function is called upon page load.
Here's my code:

```
function getP_element(){
    console.log("page loaded");
    var p_array = document.getElementById("checkboxesContainer").getElementsByTagName("p");
                for(var i=0;i<p_array.length;i++){
                    p_array[i].onmousedown = new function(){
                        return false; //this doesnt work
                    }
                }
    $("#checkboxesContainer p").click(false); //this works
}
```

EDIT:
More info about what's happening here. I created several custom `checkboxes` with custom style. Fore some reason the checkboxes get selected even when the user clicks on the `p` tags, so I figured I need to detach the `click` events. This is how they are defined inside my HTML:

```
<div id="checkBoxDiv2" class="checkBoxDiv">
                <input type='checkbox' value='someValue' id="checkBox2"/>
                <label for="checkBox2"><p class="checkBoxText">some text goes here</p>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: And how are these click handlers added in the first place ?

Comment: Why are you defining a `function` inside a loop, and why are you using `new`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have added more info to my post.

Comment: I'm slightly worried about the future of web development if you are a CS grad working as a front end developer, and you're coding like this :S

Comment: The checkboxes are supposed to get checked when clicking the ***label***, if you don't want that, just remove the `for` attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable the click event.

The checkboxes are getting selected when you click on the `p` because you have the `p` tag inside a `label` which has `for="checkBox2"`

That's what it's meant to be doing.

Remove the `for` and it will prevent clicking the label from activating the correspinding `input` element

Comment: When I remove the `for` the checkboxes dont check on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
p_array[i].onmousedown = null;
```

See [How to Clear/Remove JavaScript Event Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803936/how-to-clear-remove-javascript-event-handler)

**Edit**

The reason that the checkboxes are checked when clicking on `p` tags has nothing to do with click handlers.

Rather the reason is the [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432376/what-does-for-attribute-do-in-label-tags) attribute in the parent `label` tag. This will check the checkboxes when a click occurs on the label.

Change your HTML to

```
<label><p class="checkBoxText">some text goes here</p>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesnt work. I have added more info to my post.

Comment: Without the `for` attribute the checkboxes are not getting checked, any suggestions?

Comment: @undroid, even if you click the checkbox itself?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens.

Comment: @undroid, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?